# Java hibernate connect tables by id. What kind of connection?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, derby

I have two classes, response and coordinate. I want insert data into derby db using java hibernate annotations.

And what kind of relation declare image in bottom? ManyToOne?

db schema:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there 4 associations here, not just one.

Each of them is either a ManyToOne, or a OneToOne. Let's take `Responce.vs` as an example. If severeal Responce instances share the same Coordinate instance (i.e. is several rows in the Responce table have the same value in the `vs` column), then it's a ManyToOne. If that can't (and shouldn't) happen, then it's a OneToOne.